# Parsing Array of dictionaries in Swift using Codable

Tags: json, swift, codable

I have a JSON response from an API and I cannot figure out how to convert it into an user object (a single user) using Swift Codable. This is the JSON (with some elements removed for ease of reading):

```
{
  "user": [
    {
      "key": "id",
      "value": "093"
    },
    {
      "key": "name",
      "value": "DEV"
    },
    {
      "key": "city",
      "value": "LG"
    },
    {
      "key": "country",
      "value": "IN"
    },
    {
      "key": "group",
      "value": "OPRR"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You're unlikely to make use of `Codable` protocol in this case. This is an extremely weird way organize API data. You'd need to parse this out manually from data object.

Comment: @inokey,  agree upon you for the API response, i am finding difficult to parse it. Any other suggestion how to map it, would really help :(

Comment: In case you have word on how to organize the API, you could ask a backhander developer to return you a single object. If that's not the case well, you'd need to go a classic way for parsing json objects before Codable protocol was introduced. That'd include serializing `Data` into the `Dictionary` and parsing stuff manually by each key. Although if the list of properties could change and miss some of the fields, you'd have a hard time combining stuff into one solid User object anyway.

Comment: oh, it seems i need to go the classic way, no other option, doesn't seems the efficient way though, to map key and value. thanks for the suggestion. i would like to accept your suggestion if you put it in as answer.

Comment: Ok, I posted this as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do it in two steps if you want to. First declare a struct for the received json

```
struct KeyValue: Decodable {
    let key: String
    let value: String
}
```

Then decode the json and map the result into a dictionary using the key/value pairs.

```
do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([String: [KeyValue]].self, from: data)

    if let array = result["user"] {
        let dict = array.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.key] = $1.value}
```

Then encode this dictionary into json and back again using a struct for User

```
struct User: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let group: String
    let city: String
    let country: String
}

let userData = try JSONEncoder().encode(dict)
let user = try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: userData)
```

The whole code block then becomes

```
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let result = try decoder.decode([String: [KeyValue]].self, from: data)

    if let array = result["user"] {
        let dict = array.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.key] = $1.value}
        let userData = try JSONEncoder().encode(dict)
        let user = try decoder.decode(User.self, from: userData)
        //...
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

A bit cumbersome but no manual key/property matching is needed.

Answer (score 0):

you could try a struct with like this

```
struct Model: Codable {
    struct User: Codable {
        let key: String
        let value: String
    }
    let singleuser: [User]
}
```

Comment: I don't think that really solves the issue although this is exactly how to parse this json via Codable.

Answer (score 0):

Create a struct with 2 variables key and value

```
public struct UserModel: Codable {
    public struct User: Codable {
        public let key: String
        public let value: String
    }
    public let user: [User]
}
```

After that using JSONDecoder to decode your string.

```
func decode(payload: String) {
    do {
        let template = try JSONDecoder().decode(UserModel.self, from: payload.data(using: .utf8)!)
    } catch {
       print(error)
    }
}
```